# Why $\sin x$ not equals ${1\over\csc x}$?

Tags: functions

I was reading a maths book which stated something like:

> It is true, that: $\csc x = {1\over{\sin x}}$
>
> But, it is false, that: $\sin x = {1\over{\csc x}}$

But how is it possible, it is somehow related to their domain and range, but how and why? Are they not same?

Comment: Whenever $\csc(x)$ is defined, it is true that $\sin(x)=1/\csc(x)$.

Comment: @Clayton But the book says that, and it is confusing me a lot.

Comment: It's basically just pedantry. For the same reason, $1/(1/x)$ is not $x$, since the first is undefined at zero, while the second is defined at zero. However, in the second case it is easy to see that it is the graph of $x$ with a single point removed.

Comment: @Joppy you are confusing me more, how is that happening about $1/(1/x)$

Comment: It's a matter of notation. Let $i: \mathbb{R} \setminus 0 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $i(x) = 1/x$. Then basically I am saying that $i(i(x))$ is a different function from $x$. The only thing that goes wrong is that $i$ is not defined at zero, everywhere else they are equal. By convention, any time someone writes $1/blah$ in notation, they are really meaning $i(blah)$, and so the natural domain of the function needs to have places where $blah$ is zero removed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Joppy i get it now thnx :)

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun it is actually a module provide to me by  
an institution

Comment: @Shaun more specifically a book of notes of higher classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say I would have written a different statement if I had been the author of the book. But the statements are both true.

---

The function $\csc x$ is *defined* to be $\csc x := \frac 1{\sin x}$, and thus $\csc x$ makes sense for $x\neq 2k\pi$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. So the first sentence of your book is true since it is simply the definition of the cosecant function.

The second sentence of your book is true, that is, the equality there is false since the RHS is defined only for $x\neq 2k\pi$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ (since it contains the cosecant function, that is never $0$ by the way) and thus it cannot be equal to the LHS for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, that is the domain of the sine function. The second sentence simply means that the two expressions are equal just for $x\neq 2k\pi$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: i got it, thnx for help, nice explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

The expression $1/\sin x$ makes sense only when $\sin x \neq 0$, whereas $\sin x$ is defined for every real $x$. So the second equality holds only when both $\sin$ and $\csc$ are defined, whereas the first one makes sense when $\sin x \neq 0$.

Comment: i can't get it still, can you simplify that plz

Comment: The expression $1/x$ is not defined when $x=0$. Analogously, $1/\sin x$ is not defined when $\sin x = 0$. This means $\csc x$ is not defined at those $x$ such that $\sin x = 0$. On the other hand, the function $\sin $ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Then look at the second identity: the left hand side, $\sin x$, is defined for all $x$, but $1/\csc x$ is not defined when $\sin x = 0$ as I said before. Hence the identity $\sin x = 1/\csc x$ is not true when $\sin x = 0$.

Comment: thnx for help :)