# How to perform mathematically valid steps while finding a solution?

Tags: calculus, functions

Before having deeper understanding of Domain, I took many  mathematical steps as granted.
For e.g.

$i) \frac{1}{\frac{1}{cos(x)}}=cos(x)$

$ii)\frac{1}{cosec(x)}=sin(x)$

$iii) \sqrt{x-2}*\sqrt{x+2}=\sqrt{x^2-4}$

But after learning Domains pretty nicely, I can see the equations the new way, in more mathematically stricter sense.
Say, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{cos(x)}}$ has domain $x=R-(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ whereas $cos(x)$ has domain $R$.

Also,$\frac{1}{cosec(x)}$ has domain $(R-n\pi)$ and $sin(x)$ has domain $R$.

$\sqrt{x-2}*\sqrt{x+2}$ has domain $[2,\infty)$ whereas $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ has domain $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$.

Clearly, $i),ii),iii)$ are not always True.

In everyday life, checking and verifying every possible operation while calculating a solution makes the entire process slow and tiresome (as of my present situation).

So, what approach would be correct to follow while solving a problem? Checking and verifying every step?

Comment: Instead of checking each step, you can restrict your domain in a suitable way and keep track of it. Then at the end, check wether your solution is actually in the domain.

Comment: Expanding on the comment of @Vercassivelaunos, if at the end, there is an intersection between the domain $(D_1)$ of *all* solutions, regardless of the constraint on the domain, and the domain $(D_2)$ of **disallowed** values for $x$, then after explicitly specifying $D_1$ and $D_2$, your final answer would resemble $x \in D_1 ~:~ x \not\in D_2$.

Comment: "*Checking and verifying every step?*" Yes. Not only for the examples here, but in general. Otherwise you'll never know for sure what (you think) you proved.

Comment: The fact that functions may have non-matching domains is an important consideration, and it's good to ask about this to alleviate confusion. So, I'm not criticizing the question. ... That said, it should be noted that when one writes, say, $\frac{1}{\csc\theta}=\sin\theta$, there's an *understanding* that such an equality is to be read as asserting "the functions are equal **on their common domain**", *not* that the functions are completely identical in every way. With that understanding, i), ii), and iii) *are* "always true".

Comment: Also: [Why $\sin(x) \neq \frac1{\csc(x)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137514/why-sin-x-not-equals-1-over-csc-x)$\quad$ Another example: $\displaystyle\left[\cos(x)=0\text{ or }\tan(x)=0\right]\nRightarrow \cos(x)\tan(x)=0\implies\left[\cos(x)=0\text{ or }\tan(x)=0\right].$